# Can you recommend a free control panel app (cPanel alternative) or a special Linux distro (featuring such a panel) for a small shared web hosting?

Tags: linux, php, hosting, lamp, web

My company CEO has decided to move 3 websites the company runs to our dedicated server (which runs CRM, accounting, e-mail etc, and is not loaded much) from a shared web hosting where they are now. I've created a VM on the server and given SSH access to our webmaster.

But unfortunately the webmaster has no shell and manual web server configuration skills. It'd be great if I could set up some shared hosting control panel (like cPanel or Plesk is) so that he could manage the server himself. I'd need basic things like websites (name-based virtual hosts) management, cron tasks management, Apache/PHP/MySQL configuration etc.

Do you know of a free project of such?

Or maybe you can even recommend a special Linux distribution designed for easy shared webhosting deployment?

Answer (score 3):

How about [Webmin](http://webmin.com)? [Usermin](http://www.webmin.com/usermin.html) may also be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Comparison of Web Hosting Control Panels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_hosting_control_panels)